# How to print word that you want inside a textfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this program which it prints the text file with numbers:

```
with open('addon/entertainment.txt')as f:
    lines = []
    for l_i, line in enumerate(f.read().split('\n'), 1):  
        formatted_line = '%s. %s' % (l_i, line)  
        print(formatted_line)
        lines.append(formatted_line)
```

Output:

```
1. Synchronised Swimming Dance
2. Clown Performance
3. Magic Performance
4. House Dance Performance
5. Live Band Performance
```

What should I do to the program so that I can get entertainment such as :

```
1. Magic Performance
2. Live Band Performance
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "*I can get the Synchronised Swimming Dance and Clown Performance*"?

Comment: I have edited it. Sorry for the confusing word

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve. E.g. would you like to filter the lines in the file or rearrange them (e.g. sort)?

Comment: 1. Select the lines that you want. 2. Print them with numbers. What part is giving you difficulty?

Comment: simplify line 3 to `for l_i, line in enumerate(f, 1):`. you can access your lines aftewards by indexing the list, e.g. `lines[2]` is `'1. Magic Performance'` presumably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `readlines` and output the lines according to their `index`.

```
with open('addon/entertainment.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
       print("{}. {}".format(lines.index(line) + 1, line))

    desired_lines = [3, 5]
    output = []
    for desired in desired_lines:
        output.append(lines[desired - 1])

    for o in output:
        print("{}. {}".format(output.index(o) + 1, o))
```

Alternatively, if you want to select lines based on an `input` call, replaced `desired_lines` with:

```
desired_lines = input().split(", ")
# can choose one number or multiple numbers like this: "3, 5"
output = []
for desired in desired_lines:
    output.append(lines[int(desired) - 1])

for o in output:
    print("{}. {}".format(output.index(o) + 1, o))
```

Note that if your input goes higher than number of lines in your text file, you'll raise a `IndexError` exception.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. Really helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

This should work.. Don't have the file to test but it basically prints out all the options, asks them for what line number then prints that line number
(Or if i did it correctly it should)

```
with open('addon/entertainment.txt')as f:
lines = []
for l_i, line in enumerate(f.read().split('\n'), 1):
    print(str(num) + " : " + str(line))
uinput = int(input("What would you like to watch? (number)"))
for l_i, line in enumerate(f.read().split('\n'), 1):
    if l_i == uinput:
        formatted_line = '%s. %s' % (l_i, line)
        print(formatted_line)
    print(str(num) + " : " + str(line))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able to select multiple lines, not just one. But the question isn't clear: we don't know if he wants to select lines by menu number or by a keyword. BTW, the code in your `with` block isn't indented like it should be.

Comment: Will edit now.. Thanks.. He could just add a quick "or" statement in there if he really needs

Comment: it prints nothing. Yes, I want it to select lines by menu number .Thanks

Comment: I'd use a set of menu numbers to do the test, then you can do `if l_i in uinput:`

Comment: I have done.. Dont have the file so cannot check if it works though